# How to add the ID of cases to the list until their cumulative value reaches a threshold in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, cumsum

I have a table with two columns. First one has the ID of cases and the other one has the value. I want to add the ID's to a list, and when the cumulative value reaches a number (let's say 500000), the list should be saved and the function should continue where it left off until the end. How can I achieve this?

For Example:

Table:

ID:     1234    2345    3512    1353    1457    8756

Value:  5000    3000    498000  23000   485000  23000

output:

firstlist: (1234, 2345, 3512)
secondlist: (1353, 1457)
thirdlist: (8756)

I hope it is clear enough. Thank you in advance.

**Data as copy&paste code**

```
ID <- scan(text = "1234 2345 3512 1353 1457 8756")
Value <- scan(text = "5000 3000 498000 23000 485000 23000")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
library(purrr)

with(df, split(
  ID, 
  cumsum(c(0, head(purrr::accumulate(Value, ~if ((s <- .x + .y) > 500000) 0 else s), -1L)) == 0)
))
```

`df` looks like this

```
> df
    ID  Value
1 1234   5000
2 2345   3000
3 3512 498000
4 1353  23000
5 1457 485000
6 8756  23000
```

Output

```
$`1`
[1] 1234 2345 3512

$`2`
[1] 1353 1457

$`3`
[1] 8756
```

Comment: An error appears if I dont delete "~" before "if" function which says "unmatched opening bracket". When I delete "~", and run the code, it gives an error message: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'head': object '.x' not found

Comment: Hi @EkinKaplan, I can't reproduce your error. Can you post the code you have tried in your question?

Comment: Sure.

with(df, split(
  ID, 
  cumsum(c(0, head(purrr::accumulate(Value, if ((s <- .x + .y) > 500000) 0 else s), -1L)) == 0)
))

Comment: Hi @EkinKaplan, I still can't reproduce your problem. Can you 1) start a new rscript, 2) paste the code written above (with the `~` symbol) to that rscript, 3) run the code in that rscript, and 4) show me the full error message if any.